# How to build Go Module with a semantic version?

Tags: git, go, semantic-versioning, go-modules

Here are the bash steps to setup a new minimal Go module project with a git repo, commit it, and tag it with annotated semantic version tag:

```sh
mkdir gotest
cd gotest

git init

go mod init test.org/simple

cat <<EOT >> app.go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime/debug"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("hello world")

    if bi, ok := debug.ReadBuildInfo(); ok {
        fmt.Printf("version=%v. sum=%v\n", bi.Main.Version, bi.Main.Sum)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Failed to get build info")
    }
}
EOT

echo "simple" >> .gitignore

git add go.mod app.go .gitignore
git commit -am "initial commit"
git tag -am "initial semantic version" v0.1.0
```

Quickly verify that it's tagged correctly:

```sh
git tag -n
git describe --dirty
```

Build and run:

```sh
go build
./simple
```

That produces:

```
hello world
version=(devel). sum=
```

I was hoping to see the semantic version I tagged the repository with. Instead I got the dummy placeholder version. What is wrong?

Comment: The issue is tracked here https://github.com/golang/go/issues/29228.

Answer (score 1):

The `go` command does not query version control to determine whether your repository is a pristine checkout of a semantic version (that's https://golang.org/issue/29228).

If you build the binary with some *other* module as the main module, then the `go` command should know which version of *your* module is in use and embed that in the resulting binary:

`go.mod`:

```
module example.com/other

require test.org/simple v0.1.0
```

---

```
go build test.org/simple && ./simple
```